# Login in android with credentials

Tags: android, web-services, authentication, android-edittext

I am working on a chat application in which I have to set login Id password credentials from edittext and according to the responce , I have to go further screens.

when I am using the credentials statically, I am getting the response from the webservice

```
 String url="http://tokerapp.com/ws/get_login.php?username=rc&password=rahul";
                try {
                    String res=CustomHttpClient.executeHttpGet(url);
                    Log.e("$$$$$$$$",res);
```

but when I am taking credentials from editTexts, It is now giving me proper response.

```
    tvLogin = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editUsername);
        tvpass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editPassword);
        btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);

btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

String usrnme = tvLogin.getText().toString().trim();
String psswrd = tvpass.getText().toString().trim();

String url="http://tokerapp.com/ws/get_login.php?username=usrnme&password=psswrd";
                try {
                    String res=CustomHttpClient.executeHttpGet(url);
                    Log.e("$$$$$$$$",res);
```

Comment: yep... I dont know... that is why i asked here...

Comment: It's hard to imagine not knowing how to concatenate strings after two **days** experience with Java.  Or five seconds on Google.

Comment: He's going to be back with NetworkOnMainThreadException.

Answer (score 1):

```
String url="http://tokerapp.com/ws/get_login.php?username=" + usrnme + "&password=" + psswrd;
```

Comment: thanx Petr, One more thing I want to ask to you sir,

I am doing this in further coding, is it right??

if(res.equals(0)){
     
     Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"insert the correct id password", 8000 );
     toast.show();
     
     }
     
     else{
      Intent intentLogin = new Intent(LoginPage.this, MainActivity.class);
      startActivity(intentLogin);
     }
     }
     
     catch (Exception e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
    }